# Is it okay to use .ToList() to bypass DbContext tracking?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to keep the lifespan of my `DbContext` as short as possible, so I take advantage of the `using` statement.

However, since Entity Framework tracks the entities, I cannot do something like this :

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons()
{
    using (var db = new AppContext())
    {
        Logging.Log(Information, "Requested getPersons from service");
        return db.Persons;
    }
}
```

Because as soon as I use the list of `Persons` in my ViewModel, I will receive an InvalidOperationException (the context has been disposed before I use the object).

To bypass that, I convert the result of the query to a concrete List, by calling `ToList()`

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons()
{
    using (var db = new AppContext())
    {
        Logging.Log(Information, "Requested getPersons from service");
        return db.Persons.ToList();
    }
}
```

Is this an okay thing to do ? `AsNoTracking()` doesn't have any effects because it still returns some entity that gets dropped if the context is disposed.

Comment: Might be ok just as might not be. You don't show what you're doing with the returned collection, so we cannot say whether it's more efficient to switch to client-side evaluation or not.

Comment: The thing is I don't really feel like there is any choice. If the context gets disposed, I cannot use entites anymore, that's it. And I can't find any other way to return the objects detached from Entity Framework. You seem to suggest there are other ways to handle this, but do those ways also dispose the context immediately ? I'm actually having loads of problems dealing with the context lifespan, and I felt like disposing it immediatly was a good start.

Comment: You need to dispose a context as soon as *it makes sense to dispose it*, not immediately. If you're going to perform a query (where, select, group by, etc) on the data, let the database handle it (when possible)

Comment: I think your problem is deferred execution and not any tracking done by EF. `Persons` is an `IQueryable<Person>` nothing will execute untill it's forced to materialize. So no call to the db is done untill your viewmodel wants to know whats inside the `IEnumerable<Person>` however at this point the Context is already disposed so it can't retrieve the data from the database anymore. `ToList()` fixes this because it forces the materialization (thus the call to the database) to occur within your `using` block.

Comment: Now as for the question what's good or not depends on the use case. Lets say somebody wants to do something like this `GetPersons().Where(p => p.Id == someId)`. When returning your `ToList()` it will already have transferred all data of every person from the database to memory, and this is then searched in linear time for the right person. If you where to return an `IQueryable<Person>` and keep the context open, the query would be adjusted to only retrieve the single person. As said above it all depends on how you use it.

Comment: Please note that this is not about *tracking*. The line `db.Persons.ToList();` will make EF track all `Person` entities, so it does all but bypassing tracking. You can use `AsNoTracking()` but that won't change anything. The issue is, as commented, that the context is gone when the DbSet query is executed.

Comment: hopefully the number of persons is small because this is a SELECT *

Comment: I think it generally makes more sense to use dependency injection and match the lifetime of the request for the DbContext, but Microsoft does not say anything against using a `using` statement on it to limit its lifespan even more.

Comment: @DavidGourde thanks for mentioning dependency injection, because I slowly realise this is having a huge impact on the way I should mix that with E.F. My context is already injected at multiple places, and some entities updates I do in ViewModel A are recovered in ViewModel B through updated navigation properties, because they have the same instance. Noticed it just now, and I don't know yet how I'll refactor that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to Entities you have two options. One is simple, and the other looks even simpler but is a whole lot more complex.

The simple option:  An entity should never be referenced beyond the scope of it's DBContext.  This means in something like an MVC app, entities don't get sent to a view. They don't get serialized, they are consumed solely within the scope of their DbContext.

The key to this approach is using POCO view models and projection, (`Select` and Automapper's `ProjectTo`) and when dealing with various common layers and such, adopting something like a Unit of Work pattern to manage the lifetime scope of a DbContext.

The deceptively simple option: Detached entities. Simply ensuring the DbContext is alive when returning entities can be enough to solve your problem. A Unit of Work pattern can be leveraged for this approach as well. While it looks simple enough, it is loaded with pitfalls. Serializing an entity for instance to pass back to a view will trigger lazy load calls as the serializer traverses the entity(ies). Passing entities back to be persisted is also problematic as you have to be cautious of trying to re-attach entities where the Context may already be tracking leading to situational runtime errors,  overwriting data with stale copies, and exposing your system to unintended tampering if overly trusting the passed in entity. From a performance standpoint, this is also the worst option as you will be serializing and transmitting entire entity graphs back and forth rather than just the data a view needs.

Fixing your problem with option 2 is generally as easy as Eager Loading anything the calling code might touch. For example, if an Person has a reference to an Address:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons()
{
    using (var db = new AppContext())
    {
        Logging.Log(Information, "Requested getPersons from service");
        return db.Persons
            .Include(x => x.Address)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

However, here is where the complexity creeps in. This requires the method to know about how the Persons might be consumed. Person might have references to five or more other objects/sets, and those objects may have references to more. (I.e. Address having a reference to a Country entity, or AddressType, etc.) The catch-all fix ends up being to eager load *everything*, which results in a lot of unnecessary data and is prone to bugs as entities evolve and code grows to rely on different bits. Then when performance becomes a problem you start diving down a rabbit hole in trying to support the caller telling this method what to eager load. As the system grows and you want to support pagination, sorting, etc. the method becomes more and more complex or it becomes slower and slower.

The solution I advocate for is to ensure that entities never cross the boundary of their DbContext, and leveraging Linq/EF's `IQueryable` implementation in combination with a unit of work so that consumers of these repository or service methods can be responsible for the scope of the DbContext.  For example:

```
private AppDbContext Context
{
    get { return AmbientDbContextLocator.Get<AppDbContext>(); }
}

public IQueryable<Person> GetPersons()
{
    Logging.Log(Information, "Requested getPersons from service");
    return Context.Persons.AsQueryable();
}
```

Then in calling code:

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>(); // Can include any relevant mapping to flatten needed fields...
});
using( var contextScope = ContextScopeFactory.Create())
{
    var viewModels = PersonRepository.GetPersons()
        .ProjectTo<PersonViewModel>(mapperConfig)
        .ToList(); 
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Often you will have low-level rules such as defaulting to only returning Active rows. `.AsQueryable()` is only needed if you have no rules. Anything that results in a `.Where` or such inside the repository/service method returns `IQueryable` so it could return:

```
    return Context.Persons.Where(x => x.IsActive);
```

Repositories can enforce low level filtering rules like IsActive, authorization checks, etc. leaving more variable filtering, sorting, etc. up to the consumers.

The advantage of this approach is that the consumer (Controller, etc.) has full control over how the data is consumed without introducing any complexity/business logic into the repository/service. If I want to support sorting and pagination:

```
    var viewModels = PersonRepository.GetPersons()
        .OrderBy(x => x.Age)
        .ProjectTo<PersonViewModel>(mapperConfig)
        .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();
```

The key point is that the entity (Person) doesn't leave the scope of the unit of work / DbContext, it is projected into a ViewModel which holds no references to entities, only data. That model can be safely serialized and represents only the data that the view needs. For projection I've used Automappper's `ProjectTo` as an example. You can use Linq's `Select` as a more manual option. The unit of work pattern I use and have outlined above is Mehdime's DbContextScope.

Comment: *An entity should never be referenced beyond the scope of its DBContext* -- IMO that's too strict. I think it's fine to do so, as long as they don't *need* the context anymore, f.e for lazy loading. For simple CRUDs it may be fine to sent entities up and down clients and backends.

Comment: For short-lived, simple systems I don't think there is anything wrong with working with detached entities. Systems that are designed a specific way, fill their purpose and never really go through much revision. For larger, more complex systems that have requirements that grow and evolve over time, working with detached entities can be a recipe for considerable complexity, and with complexity comes bugs, performance issues, and compromises. My point was merely that passing entities around can *look* like a simple solution, but requires a fair bit of work to avoid issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you just return `db.Persons` which is an `IEnumerable<Person>` to some caller and then dispose the db context before that caller can iterate the result, you will get the exception, due to the lazy nature by default of entity framework.  `ToList` gets around this by forcing iteration immediately before the context is disposed, but still has overhead for object tracking, so combining `ToList` with `AsNoTracking` gets you the best performance.

`AsNoTracking` removes some internal tracking code inside the db context, it does not allow you to pass out the `IEnumerable<Person>` after disposing the context, you still need `ToList` for that.

Use the extension method `AsNoTracking` and then call `ToList`:

```cs
db.Persons.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Or you can disable change tracking on the change tracker property of the db context to make the whole thing read only, which avoids having to call `AsNoTracking` everywhere. You still need `ToList` with this approach.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Disable all change tracking - place in db context sub class
/// </summary>
public void DisableChangeTracking()
{
    ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
}
```

Comment: See my last notes in the answer which cover the case where I believe he was passing the IEnumerable of just db.Persons all the way out after disposing the db context.

Comment: Hopefully it helps some passers by that don't understand the deferred nature and may be confused by what as no tracking does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! This whole `AsNoTracking` confusion has been induced by my wrong understanding of what it does. Unsure right now if I can simply disable LazyLoading because some of our tables will get pretty big, so it will need some performance testing, which isn't the subject for now.

Answer (score 0):

It is acceptable to do so. The problem with `IEnumerable` is that `Entity Framework` supports deferred execution, so they won't be populated until you fetch them to a concrete collection (i.e. `.ToList()`), which could happen after it's been disposed of.

Your 2 possibilities are:

- Executing the work on the deferred object by fetching it to a concrete collection (`.ToList()`).
- Using dependency injection with a scoped Lifetime to let it live until the request completes.

Both are correct, and which one to prefer depends on your use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I feel like solution N°2 induces that the E.F. repository and the consumer are aware they share the same DbContext (because I won't be allowed to use a `Dispose()` anymore when my fetching is done .. Is that a problem ?